# What is best way of keeping two database schema in synch?

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, schema, replication

We have two SQL server database, and one is kept in US and being changed from day to day and the other one is in India. What is the best way of keeping two database schema in synch. Does any functionality like sql server replication help?

Comment: Are these development databases?

Answer (score 5):

If you use replication, then when you change schema on one side, then you must republish those articles, and re-synch just those things that changed.

If you are making changes via script, then simply apply the change scripts to both databases.
EDIT: In fact, if you KNOW you are making changes to two databases, I HIGHLY recommend creating a change script that you can run on both.

If you are not sure if the schemas are in synch, then we use [Red Gates SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm). It's a fantastic tool (and no, I don't work for them)

Comment: Visual Studio Data Dude / Database Edition has excellent tools for diffing DBs and generating update scripts for the schema.  Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Replication cannot really help if the schema is changing.

Is the schema changing on both sides?

A tool like Red Gate's SQL Compare or Apex's similar tool can look at two databases, determine the differences and generate scripts to make one the same as the other.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up creating schema comparison in VS2010 and that served quite well for my purpose.